# React router: how to pass param from URL into component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

For example, if I have

```
<Route path='/contacts/:name' render={() => (
    <div>Hello, { name } </div>
)} />
```

How do I pull the :name param to use in the render?

Comment: `{props.match.params.name}`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it-

```
    <Route path='/contacts/:name' render={(props) => (
      <div>Hello, { props.match.params.name } </div>
    )} />
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be part of the `match` object that gets passed in as props.

```
<Route path='/contacts/:name' render={({ match }) => (
    <div>Hello, { match.params.name } </div>
)} />
```